# IndexOf, encrypting, array help in java

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, indexof

I know I'm not supposed to do this but I am a beginner and I need help on this. I am wondering what I need in each number on the bottom. I am not asking for the code but just help on what to use.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/elSuPgW.png]

**Clarification:**

What the problem is asking for is to go through the String one character at a time.

A "valid" word is written backwards in between ? and &

```
example: valid would be encrypted as ?dilav&
```

The entire message of encrypted words are also in reverse order.

I hope I made it more clear

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? Which part of this assignment is not clear? Also bonus question: why are you asking strangers rather then your teacher?

Comment: The stuff after it says "You must write the code to parse an encrypted message." so I did number 1 with a.length();. But I don't know what to use for the rest of them. I wanted to know what I can use to solve #2,3,4,5. It would be greatly appreciated. And tbh my teacher doesn't help much, I think you guys would be better help.

Comment: what language? seems like you can do this using procedural like c

Comment: teacher doe not help much, thats common for programming courses because you cannot teach programming you have to experience it!

Comment: Are you saying that you already created code that decrypt massage but you have problems with interpreting what to do with it like printing number of words? Printing list of words?

Comment: "write the code to automate the decryption 
process using the following information" and the picture is the information that was given to me. I didn't write the code to decrypt  the message yet, I need help on that. All I did was #1 on the bottom (Original length of the encrypted message).  Basically #3,4,5 is decrypting it. But also need help on #2. I think IndexOf is supposed to be used ?

Comment: So you used `size()` method of `String`.  That was no brainer. Now start thinking. `Jason` gave you good instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by thinking how you would solve this in your head.

You would start at the left and look at each character until you found a '?'. Then you would note the letters until you found a '&'. Bingo, first word. Continue until you have all the words.

Now you know how many words you have (answer #2).

Then you need to reverse the letters in each word.

Now print them in the order you found them (answer #3).

Now print them in reverse order - the last word first (answer #4).

Now print the reversed list with spaces between them (answer #5).

Sample code (please try to understand how it works and don't just copy it and hand it in - or your teacher will ask you to explain how it works):

```
public static void main(final String[] args){

    // example provided by Jason via Stackoverflow

    String message = "&*#$@?ebyam,&?siht&=asdf???od&failure???&?on?nac&the%%@?uoy&horizon!";

    System.out.println("#1: " + message.length());

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    int questionPos = message.indexOf("?");
    while(questionPos > -1) {
        message = message.substring(questionPos + 1, message.length());

        int ampersandPos = message.indexOf("&");
        questionPos = message.indexOf("?");

        if(ampersandPos > 0 && (ampersandPos < questionPos || questionPos == -1)) {
            String word = message.substring(0, ampersandPos);
            StringBuilder reversedWord = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reversedWord.append(word.charAt(i));
            }
            words.add(reversedWord.toString());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("#2: " + words.size());

    System.out.println("#3:");
    for(final String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    System.out.println("#4:");
    for(int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(words.get(i));
    }

    System.out.print("#5: ");
    for(int i = words.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(i < words.size() - 1) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(words.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of all this in my head. But I don't know what code I am supposed to use to do this, that's the thing.

Comment: Start by looking at String in the Java docs. See what methods are available for extracting characters. Your hunch about indexOf is a good place to start. Try message.indexOf("?") to see where the next '?' is.

Comment: What do you think your code should do? What operations would you need? Have you checked methods of `String` class? You can also consider using `StringBuilder` for word characters and implementation of `List` for words.

Comment: I'll try that Jason and I'm not sure what you mean Pshemo, but I'll look into StringBuilder, haven't used that yet

Comment: You'll also want to use String.substring to extract parts of a string where you have identified the beginning and end of the bit you want.

Comment: Alright I'm doing it, but look now I used 
                int left = a.indexOf("?");
  int right = a.indexOf("&");
  String sub = a.substring(left+1, right);

and I am trying to find text between ? and &. but there is an index out of range error and I see why but I don't know how to fix it. The first & is all the way in the beginning of the message but i am trying to disregard that but how.  My friend is saying you might need a loop and if statement

Comment: When indexOf returns -1, it means it couldn't find what you told it to look for. So before using 'left' and 'right' in the substring call, make sure that they aren't -1.

Comment: Also, the rules in your problem don't say how to handle ???od&. But carry on and then figure out how to handle this special case later.

Comment: Look for the first '?' and throw away the part of the message before it. Then look for the first '&'. That should allow you to extract the first word.

Comment: In the message, When I try to find text between ? and & it goes back and thinks I'm trying to find text in between the first ? and the & that came at -6 from indexOf(?). But I am not trying to find it in between those 2. I am trying to find it between the ? and the other & not the first one.

Comment: I am supposed to move onto the next question mark where it's ???od& i think so

Comment: How can i throw away the message before it ? Sorry but thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks for the big help man. I am going to go to sleep now and work on it tomorrow so I'll look through the sample code you provided then. I'm pretty sure I'll understand what I've been doing wrong and what I've been missing by analyzing and reading through the sample code you provided. If I have any more questions, I might ask. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, thanks for all your time. It was greatly appreciated!